# Way to get the SearchPath API to not look in c:\windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way to get the [SearchPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to not search in c:\windows when using the default search path (passing NULL as the first param)? I can't modify the caller to send in a specific path.

I have a system with an application ini file in c:\windows (which I don't want it to use, but for legacy reasons has to remain there). I put my copy of the same ini file in c:\users\public, and put c:\users\public at the front of my system path environment variable, but a call to [SearchPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) still finds the c:\windows version. If I delete that version, it then finds the c:\users\public version, so I know the path was set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527(VS.85).aspx), there's nothing you can do about this bar changing a system level (HKLM) registry entry (Which is a "bad thing"). The registry change would cause the search order to start with the current working directory, which you could set to the desired folder in a shortcut. (Again, I'm going to say; changing a Machine Level registry entry to do this - is potentially dangerous!)

Have you looked into [application shims](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457032.aspx)? This may be something that could work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very late, but having just run into this problem myself, I would propose a better solution.

The first argument to [SearchPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365527.aspx), as you have found, can be used to specify the directories you want it to search, instead of the default order.  You can retrieve and use the current user's PATH with [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188.aspx), and then search within that:

```
DWORD err = GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", NULL, 0);
char* path = new char[err+1];   path[err] = 0;
GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, err);

err = SearchPath(path, "application", ".ini", 0, NULL, NULL);
char* searchResult = new char[err+1];   searchResult[err] = 0;
err = SearchPath(path, "application", ".ini", err, searchResult, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `SetCurrentDirectory("c:\users\public")` and then `SearchPath(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, SearchPath is called inside a lib, so I really shouldn't be messing with the applications current directory. Also, different users will want to use different paths, I can't hard code it. I'll use an environment var users can set and I will use that path instead of passing NULL to SearchPath.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the best solution.